Removing image overlay marks after image merging
I am using the code below to merge two images. The code uses the OpenCV library to find the overlap between two images and combines them. I'm getting the error of having image overlay marks in the panorama. I would like to know how I can remove (or reduce) these overlapping marks.
I tried using this code from this repository:
import cv2
import numpy as np
import sys

class Image_Stitching():
    def __init__(self) :
        self.ratio=0.85
        self.min_match=10
        self.sift=cv2.SIFT.create()
        self.smoothing_window_size=800

    def registration(self,img1,img2):
        kp1, des1 = self.sift.detectAndCompute(img1, None)
        kp2, des2 = self.sift.detectAndCompute(img2, None)
        matcher = cv2.BFMatcher()
        raw_matches = matcher.knnMatch(des1, des2, k=2)
        good_points = []
        good_matches=[]
        for m1, m2 in raw_matches:
            if m1.distance < self.ratio * m2.distance:
                good_points.append((m1.trainIdx, m1.queryIdx))
                good_matches.append([m1])
        img3 = cv2.drawMatchesKnn(img1, kp1, img2, kp2, good_matches, None, flags=2)
        cv2.imwrite('matching.jpg', img3)
        if len(good_points) > self.min_match:
            image1_kp = np.float32(
                [kp1[i].pt for (_, i) in good_points])
            image2_kp = np.float32(
                [kp2[i].pt for (i, _) in good_points])
            H, status = cv2.findHomography(image2_kp, image1_kp, cv2.RANSAC,5.0)
        return H

    def create_mask(self,img1,img2,version):
        height_img1 = img1.shape[0]
        width_img1 = img1.shape[1]
        width_img2 = img2.shape[1]
        height_panorama = height_img1
        width_panorama = width_img1 +width_img2
        offset = int(self.smoothing_window_size / 2)
        barrier = img1.shape[1] - int(self.smoothing_window_size / 2)
        mask = np.zeros((height_panorama, width_panorama))
        if version== 'left_image':
            mask[:, barrier - offset:barrier + offset ] = np.tile(np.linspace(1, 0, 2 * offset ).T, (height_panorama, 1))
            mask[:, :barrier - offset] = 1
        else:
            mask[:, barrier - offset :barrier + offset ] = np.tile(np.linspace(0, 1, 2 * offset ).T, (height_panorama, 1))
            mask[:, barrier + offset:] = 1
        return cv2.merge([mask, mask, mask])

    def blending(self,img1,img2):
        H = self.registration(img1,img2)
        height_img1 = img1.shape[0]
        width_img1 = img1.shape[1]
        width_img2 = img2.shape[1]
        height_panorama = height_img1
        width_panorama = width_img1 +width_img2

        panorama1 = np.zeros((height_panorama, width_panorama, 3))
        mask1 = self.create_mask(img1,img2,version='left_image')
        panorama1[0:img1.shape[0], 0:img1.shape[1], :] = img1
        panorama1 *= mask1
        mask2 = self.create_mask(img1,img2,version='right_image')
        panorama2 = cv2.warpPerspective(img2, H, (width_panorama, height_panorama))*mask2
        result=panorama1+panorama2

        rows, cols = np.where(result[:, :, 0] != 0)
        min_row, max_row = min(rows), max(rows) + 1
        min_col, max_col = min(cols), max(cols) + 1
        final_result = result[min_row:max_row, min_col:max_col, :]  
        return final_result
def main(argv1,argv2):
    img1 = cv2.imread(argv1)
    img2 = cv2.imread(argv2)
    final=Image_Stitching().blending(img1,img2)
    cv2.imwrite('panorama.jpg', final)

I expected the image without the overlay marks, but I don't know how to remove them.
I'm using the images below:
Left image
Right image
I appreciate any help. Thanks for your time.

please upload the two images so we can reproduce your problem

thank you, by the sugestion. I did the upload.

This is a good method: https://www.crisluengo.net/archives/393/ — read also the earlier post linked there for more explanation.
